# Automating the installation using SSH

Tags: ssh, automation, shell-script

I am running a bash script from a remote host to run a binary file which installs 64 bit JDK 6 update 29 on multiple VMs across the Environment.
It is installing the file but, at the last line i have to hit a enter to complete the installation. I want to fully automate the script where i do not have to hit the enter at the last line. This is what i am using

```
ssh ${V_TIERS}@${V_TIERS} 'cd JDK; sh jdk-6u29-solaris-sparcv9.sh'
```

It updates as desired, but during install i have to hit enter to continue and complete the installation. Can anybody please help to fully automate the update process.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ssh ${V_TIERS}@${V_TIERS} 'cd JDK; echo | sh jdk-6u29-solaris-sparcv9.sh'
```